# On form errors, (422 Unprocessable Entity) rails current_page? helper is not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activesupport, ruby-on-rails-7

On form errors in rails 7, (422 Unprocessable Entity) rails current_page? helper is not working.
https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-current_page-3F

I think it's related with turbo drive but i cannot find how to solve it.

GET to http://127.0.0.1:3000/record_metadata/new

```
current_page?(controller: 'record_metadata', action: 'new')
=> true
```

#### ... after unvalid form post request

controller renders :new action and logs says...

`Processing by RecordMetadataController#create as TURBO_STREAM`

...

```
 Completed 422 Unprocessable Entity in 172ms
```

url remains same

```
current_page?(controller: 'record_metadata', action: 'new')
=> false
current_page?(controller: 'record_metadata', action: 'edit')
=> false
current_page?(controller: 'record_metadata', action: 'create')
=> false
current_page?(controller: 'record_metadata', action: 'update')
=> false
```

I tried all solutions but it can't work.

Comment: I think you just have the wrong expections. When you submit a request with invalid input to create or update a record and then call `render :new` or `render :edit` you're not redirecting  the user so its still being rendered by the `create/update` method. This is a pretty common Rails beginner hangup.

Comment: The `new` and `edit` methods are merely used to render forms that you can visit via `GET` requests while `create` and `update` show the results of performing a non-idempotent requests via POST and PATCH. See https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#crud-verbs-and-actions

Comment: Ok i know create and update methods whats for. Thanks for remanding again but it not works. I tried all documentation examples and google examples. It is simply not working. After unsuccessful post, create method rendering :new method, somehow rails 7 use turbo which maybe related for this problem. I can not find solution yet.